# Regex to match from beginning of the line till the first colon

Tags: c#, regex

My example string would be like

```
Abc: abc
bcd: abc

cde: abc
--------
Def: abc.
```

I want to match `Abc:`, `Bcd:`, `Cde:`, and `Def:`.

So far I've tried `\n*:\B` but this one matches `:` only on first line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: `^[^:]*:`.

Read it as "beginning of string/line followed by any number of non-colon characters followed by a colon."

**EDIT**

In C#, I think you'd want something like this, assuming `text` is a string containing that whole thing (newlines and all):

```
new Regex(@"^[^:]*:", RegexOptions.Multiline).Matches(text);
```

If you're matching each line one at a time, it should be this:

```
new Regex(@"^[^:]*:").Match(line);
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick and detailed response. It seems like it does the job.